# Sample SOAP Request for Oracle Flexcube FCUBSSMService

Tags: oracle, soap, soapui, identity-management

I am looking to automate user provisioning for Oracle Flexcube through APIs using FCUBSSMService SOAP Service, however due to lack of knowledge on Oracle I am having challenges in identifying the correct SOAP Service request from the available documentation. If someone can refer a working example for QueryUserMaint or any other API, or provide a documentation reference would be great

Tried this request

````
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fcub:fcubviceHeader>
         <fcub:fcubvice>FCUBSSMfcubvice</fcub:fcubvice>
         <fcub:Operation>QueryUfcubMaint</fcub:Operation>
         <fcub:MessageId>1234</fcub:MessageId>
         <fcub:CorrelationId>5678</fcub:CorrelationId>
      </fcub:fcubviceHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fcub:QueryUfcubMaint_Input>
         <fcub:P_UfcubID>Jane</fcub:P_USERID>
      </fcub:QueryUserMaint_Input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>```


But the response doesnot return anything only http/11 200 OK
````

Comment: Did you get your call to work? I'm also trying to figure out how to communicate with Flexcube and documentation is pretty lacking. Any chance you can share you full soap envelope content?